# 'exceptions.RuntimeError' - Object has no attribute 'errno'

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I'm working with Maya 2018 and there's a weird thing going on. When I select multiple vertices, faces or edges I get:

```
// Error: AttributeError: file <string> line 88: 'exceptions.RuntimeError' object has no attribute 'errno' // 
// Warning: Python callback failed //
```

The problem with this in what I'm scripting is that when this warning/error appears, somehow it does not let me click on my custom GUI buttons.
For example. I need to select a few vertices then click a button to save them into a custom attribute... Well I can't click that button right away, and I'm guessing it is because of this weird error.

Any ideas on what this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line 88 of your script you're trying to use attribute `errno` of `RuntimeError` instance but this exception class has no such attribute.
Read [documentation of exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) before trying to handle them.

Atrribute `errno` is defined only in [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) and classes inheriting from it.
So apparently line 88 is part of `try...except` clause and in that line you're trying to use `e.errno`. You can't do that if the exception doesn't belong to `OSError` exceptions family.

Comment: Well. I'm not using it at line 88....   my line 88 is: `code`( leftTableWidget = QWidget())   ... The documentation only says it is 'A numeric error code from the C variable errno' ... I get this might be a simple issue for you but you answer didn't really help how to solve it.... also there is no 'try except' in  my code...  where should i handle this error?

Comment: @MendelReis the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError describes `OSError` class and it's attribute `errno`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError documentation doesn't mention attribute `errno` so it doesn't have it. Sometimes tools mess up the actual line numbers - please search for occurences of `errno` in your script and it would be the best if you could paste `try...except` block in which `errno` is used. Also does the traceback have only one line? If not, please include the traceback in your question.

Comment: If there's no `try...except` block in your code, then the traceback should be longer than just `Error: AttributeError: file <string> line 88: 'exceptions.RuntimeError' object has no attribute 'errno' //` - please include the full traceback.

Comment: As far as my abilities let me understand, that is the whole trace back.. sorry.  Do you work with maya? here's git hub [link](https://github.com/mreis/faceTweakRigger)  with the whole script. you can run it in maya 2017 or 2018 and see if you get the error when selecting vertices.   bit chances this is a silly thing indeed, but those silly things are the most annoying to beginners...  Thank you.