# Making connection request to microsoft azure services using http.client.https.connnection for analyzing Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use the azure service-Computer vision for analyzing an Image with python3.7. While trying to make a connection request, an error is shown.
It looks like the parameter(url) I am giving for httpsConnection is wrong, But I dont know how to rectify it.

The problem is with the API endpoint. The endpoint I have given is correct but the parameter is asking for integer value(that's what I understood).

```
def analyze_image(data):
    try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('https://xxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com/')
        conn.request("POST", "/vision/v1.0/analyze?%s" % params, str(data), headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        data = response.read()
        print(str(data))
        conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

    return data
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rupali Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 887, in _get_hostport
    port = int(host[i+1:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '//rupali.cognitiveservices.azure.com/'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rupali Singh/PycharmProjects/Drishti/ms_visionapi.py", line 44, in analyze_image
    conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('https://rupali.cognitiveservices.azure.com/')
  File "C:\Users\Rupali Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1373, in __init__
    blocksize=blocksize)
  File "C:\Users\Rupali Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 851, in __init__
    (self.host, self.port) = self._get_hostport(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Rupali Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 892, in _get_hostport
    raise InvalidURL("nonnumeric port: '%s'" % host[i+1:])
http.client.InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: '//rupali.cognitiveservices.azure.com/'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Rupali Singh/PycharmProjects/Drishti/ms_visionapi.py", line 85, in <module>
    data = analyze_image(img)
  File "C:/Users/Rupali Singh/PycharmProjects/Drishti/ms_visionapi.py", line 51, in analyze_image
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
AttributeError: 'InvalidURL' object has no attribute 'errno'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the value of your `params` var that you are trying to add to your url?

Comment: Please refer the following link for Computer vision analyze Image REST API and Python Code in code samples.
https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa

Comment: Check this thread where you should find answer to your 'errno' issue:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48541077/exceptions-runtimeerror-object-has-no-attribute-errno

Answer (score 0):

You should use the host name without the `https://` part.

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('xxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com')
```

But the http module is quite clunky and sometimes give you unhelpful error messages. Instead, I recommend using the official python client for Microsoft Azure Cognitive Services Computer Vision Client Library for Python.

https://pypi.org/project/azure-cognitiveservices-vision-computervision/

If you don't want to use that library, or want to connect to a different http api, use [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/).